# How to use Maven and various application.properties for artifact generation of different testing regions in a Spring configured app

Tags: java, spring, maven, continuous-integration

I want to use Maven to handle artifact generation for the different local and testing regions. I believe I can use different profiles but I am not certain.

**In Maven can I select different directories to select files used on packaging (such as application.properties)? How would I set that up?**

An idea of what I want is to have a the following folders for resources in my project

- local
- build server
- dev
- sys
- prod

Each folder should contain a different version of application.resources which is a file in Spring that can be used to handle hard-coded strings for use in variables. For local builds- our developers also work on different operating systems. Should I require I want to make it seamless on different OS' also.

Key outcomes would be:

- Control [Maven lifecycle phases](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html) from inside the IDE (IntelliJ)
- Not complicate phases and team processes
- Keep things as consistent for each developer
- Make the different configurations per developer/region appear invisible when running a phase e.g. install

Ideally I would have my project set up according to [best practices (Duvall, Matyas, Glover)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321336380).

Comment: use maven profiles (http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) and resources filtering (http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Spring boot, there is an easy way of doing this.

Create two profiles in maven, and set a property in each profile with the name of the Spring profile you want to execute.

```
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <!-- Default spring profile to use -->
            <spring.profiles.active>dev</spring.profiles.active>
            <!-- Default environment -->
            <environment>develop</environment>
        </properties>
    </profile>
```

Inside your application.properties, add this property:
spring.profiles.active=${spring.profiles.active}

Create an application.property for each profile, using this pattern application-profile.properties. For example:
application-dev.properties 
application-prod.properties

Be sure to active filtering in the resource plugin:

```
  ...
  <resource>
    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
    <filtering>true</filtering>
  </resource>
 ...
```

Another way is to create a file during the execution of maven called activeprofile.properties. Spring boot looks this file to load the active profile. You can create this file as follows:

```
   <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <target>
                            <echo message="spring.profiles.active=${spring.profiles.active}" file="target/classes/config/activeprofile.properties" />
                        </target>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 4):

We provide different properties currently but not by way of different folders. We do this 
via a mix of

- Spring's `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`
- Maven profiles (something we use to build our Dev environment),
- Build Server (TeamCity in our case)
- Maven phases to produce the correct artifact
- start-up and build arguments

My understanding of what we do is limited, but hopefully this serves as a useful example for others and maybe myself to consider.

We provide parameters, as you'll see below, to point to different property files. 
Each property file has configuration for a region/environment. I'll explain the current use 
as best I can in-case it provides some use to others.

To use Maven profiles we have created a `profile` in our pom identified as `development` which includes a region configuration property called `env`. I don't yet know entirely how that is being used yet in our project however you'll see below our POM includes the a Maven Compiler plugin and a Maven Tomcat plugin.

Day to day, as developers we run our our applications locally on Tomcat from within IntelliJ 
and provide the `env` property. On start-up the `env` property is provided as an argument to 
set to `classpath*:dev-common.properties`.
This file is a properties configuration file - setting placeholder values for our different
regions.

The value of `env` is made available to our `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`

---

**Example 1** - Implementation of Maven `profile` in pom.xml:

The implementation of a `profile` in our pom is:

```xml
<profile>
        <id>development</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>env</name>
                <value>development</value>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <pluginManagement>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.3.2</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <source>1.6</source>
                            <target>1.6</target>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                        <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            ...
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </pluginManagement>
        </build>
    </profile>
```

---

**Example 2** - Property placeholder configurer for normal build:

We also make use ofa Spring component, a `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`. We use this in collaboration with a build argument to set up a classpath *pointer* to resource files.

```xml
<bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>
                ${env}
            </value>
        </list>
    </property>
```

---

**Example 3** - Property placeholder configurer for test:

We have Spring Contexts specifically set up for integration testing which also use the `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`. These are picked up by a integration testing class using a combination of `@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:test-dataexchange-application-context.xml"})` and `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)`).

In the *testing context* we configure the `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` as follows to pick up the properties of an integration testing region:

```xml
<bean id="testpropertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath*:dev-local-common.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
```

---

**Other notes:**

We make use of Team City for build management but I have not seen how these settings are
used there, if they are at all. I can conceive there's an ability to combine the above approaches together to aid Continuous Integration and Delivery.

I do not see where the profile identified as `development` is being used. It is something I 
must follow up with my fellow team members.

---

**Resources:**

- [Building for different environments](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-building-for-different-environments.html) at the Maven Project site.
- Maven 3 does not allow configuration of a `profile` outside of a pom or settings.xml (the Maven configuration file) and says that users who used these external settings [should now put them inside of settings.xml](https://cwiki.apache.org/MAVEN/maven-3x-compatibility-notes.html#Maven3.xCompatibilityNotes-profiles.xml)

Answer (score 1):

Aim to generate an artifact for each environment at one time on the central server (CI/Build server), aim to generate an artifact and start/test the application with one click locally, provide a consistent easy to learn way to check out and run your build, and check in and configure your CI.

You can use profiles in Maven and utilize Maven targets to achieve the right build using a build server which in our case is TeamCity.

Use property placeholder configurer in Spring context with an `application.resources` file for each region and a filename mask e.g. `application-resources-${region}`.